# Copy entire directory and content from one location to another using PHP

Tags: php, directory, copy

I am trying to copy an entire folder from one location to another using PHP, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$username = "peter" //this is just an example.
$userdir = "../Users/".$username."/";
mkdir($userdir);// create folder 

// copy image folder
$source = "templates/template1/images/";//copy image folder -source
$dest = $userdir;

function copyr($source, $dest){
// Simple copy for a file
if (is_file($source)) {
$c = copy($source, $dest);
chmod($dest, 0777);
return $c;
}

// Make destination directory
if (!is_dir($dest)) {
$oldumask = umask(0);
mkdir($dest, 0777);
umask($oldumask);
}

// Loop through the folder
$dir = dir($source);
while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
// Skip pointers
if ($entry == "." || $entry == "..") {
continue;
}

}

// Clean up
$dir->close();
return true;
}
```

I have also tried other solutions I saw online   without success. Would appreciate any help possible

---

I also just tried this script without any luck.

I just tried another script and still no luck :(.

```
$template_homepage = "templates/template1/index.php";//path to default template homepage
$homepage = file_get_contents($template_homepage);//get default homepage structure


$username = testuser;// folder name for store


if (trim($username) == '') {
die("An error occured.");
} else {
$userdir = "../Users/".$username."/";
mkdir($userdir);// create folder for new website

// copy image folder
$src = 'templates/template1/images';//copy image folder -source
$dst = $userdir;

   function rcopy($src, $dst) {
  if (file_exists($dst)) rrmdir($dst);
  if (is_dir($src)) {
mkdir($dst);
$files = scandir($src);
foreach ($files as $file)
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") rcopy("$src/$file", "$dst/$file"); 
}
  else if (file_exists($src)) copy($src, $dst);

}




$fh = fopen($userdir."index.php", 'w') or die("An error occured. ");// create home page in users folder

   // $stringData = $title; //."\n";//
   fwrite($fh, $homepage);// write homepage structure into new homepage file.
    fclose($fh);// close new homepage file.
 $launchpage = "../Users/".$username."/"; // launch new homepage file.
header("Location: $launchpage");
   }
```

Comment: do you have permission in the dest directory?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and use the OS command to copy the folder over?

```
exec('cp -r sourcedir destdir');
```

Comment: I dont know how to do that. is it possible for you to help me out? PLS

Comment: Just tried this and its not working.


    $userdir = "../Users/".$username."/";
    mkdir($userdir);// create folder for new website
 
       // copy image folder
 $src = "/templates/template1/images";//copy image folder -source
    $des = $userdir;
 
    shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");

Comment: were you able to confirm that $userdir was successfully created after calling mkdir($userdir)?

Comment: yes $userdir directory was created successfully, I have tried several samples i have seen online and none is working. Could this be my server setup???

Comment: I am running Apache, MySQL and PHP on a windows 7 machine.

Comment: if the directory was created successfully, then you have enough permission I presume. You can actually get the return value of your exec() statement. Or try to do copying first in the command line to check so you can actually see if there is really a problem in the server. By the way, I apologize for not replying soon. I didn't get any notification that you have replied to my comment.

Comment: Ehis, you need to change the cp command to copy in Windows as cp is a unix command.